# Wordpress (6.0.1) Login Redirect Loop on (LAMP) Ubuntu Server (22.04)

Tags: server, apache2, login, wordpress

I'm using on my Raspberry PI 4 --> Ubuntu Server (Linux 5.4.0-1044-raspi aarch64), with Apache2, mySQL, PHP 7.1, let's encrypt certificate with Wordpress 6.0.1.

I want to switch the URL of my website.

For both Domains the SSL certificates are created and also under /etc/apache2/sites-available/ VirtualHost-config-files active and working.

I'm using in Wordpress 15 plugins. At the moment everything is working fine.

But when I switch URL at Wordpress to the new one, I can't login to Wordpress Admin-Panel.

So I restored from a backup and then I first disabled all Wordpress plugins and when I disable the plugin "WPS hide login" then login is also not working. This plugin set the default login URL .../wp-login.php to a custom URL.

So when all plugins are disabled I login at get redirected back to the login-page without any error message.

I tried this things:

- Delete my browser cookies
- Restart Apache Service
- Restart Server
- Moved .htaccess file
- Doing manual WordPress Update with blank wordpress-6.0.1.zip file –> replacing all wp-files.
- Disable http to https redirect
- Activated Debug-Mode in Wordpress --> No useful log-entry.

Login to Admin-Panel still not working.

Last thing I tried yesterday is deleting wordpress at /var/www/wordpress + mysql-database and installed a new Wordpress site. --> Login also then not working.

After that I restored again from backup.

Because it's not working at a new Wordpress installation too, there should be a problem at apache2/ubuntu. I don't know why login is working with active plugin "WPS hide login".

The question is how can I figure out what cause this issue at login to Wordpress backend? Maybe there is a security setting at apache2.

Comment: WordPress has a lot of domain settings in the database. If you change the domain, you will need to manually connect to the MySQL database and modify a number of configuration settings in the settings table. You may also need to update the URLs for your posts/comments depending on which plugins you’re using.

Comment: Hi, thank you for this hint. I think I have descripted it not correctly. 
I'm at the step before I will change the URL of Wordpress. When I deactivate the WP-plugin "WPS hide login" I can't login to Wordpress-backend, the Domain of the Website was not changed. I then have a "Login Redirect Loop" where I get this redirect-URL from the description. I tried the typical things, but nothing is helping.
The question is how can I debug this on ubuntu/apache2, because Wordpress-Debug is not logging any issue. Maybe there is a problem in the mysql database, but I don't know where.

Comment: Instead of putting **EDIT --> SOLVED:** at the end of your question please answer your own question and click the check mark beside your answer to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your tips.

I have no clue where the problem was at my Wordpress. Something seems to be damaged in the core files or database. I used this Wordpress installation over 2 years. Maybe an update in the past went wrong... I have tried many things to repair it but nothing helped.

So I installed a secound Wordpress at the new URL. Login is much faster there than at my old Wordpress. I have used the build in Wordpress export and import to transfer all of the content. Checked all settings page by page and disabled the old Wordpress in apache2.

Now with the fresh installation it working again.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some methods that you can try:

1, Temporarily disable caching plugins like wp-rocket, wp-super-cache (if available)... by renaming it in wp-content/plugins. It looks: wp-super-cache -> .wp-super-cache.

2, Check class file wp-config.php delete define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', 'youdomain.com'); if you've ever set up.

3, Finally if 1,2 fail, login to database using phpmyadmin, adminer, sql via ssh, create new admin user (sql command), after login admin wordpress manager recover password by sending request reset password.